# How to click allow/block on chrome browser modal(authenticator) in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

Have issue with clicking allow or block button in the attached screen

[image: Webauthn authentication browser popup]

If there is a way to disable that window that will also help. When doing manually pressing Enter/Esc on keyboard will cancel that popup

Tried different approaches.
1) `getDriver().switchTo().alert().accept()`: No alert present exception
2)`action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE); 
action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`;
3)Tried Robot framework also 
4)Disabled notifications/popup is not disabling this popup

Any inputs will help

did any one faced this issue. How to resolve it.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a switch to prevent the prompt from appearing at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc but I could not find one to turn it off.